# Cannot update from Windows 10 Build 10240

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-upgrade

My current version of Windows 10 is Build **10240** (x64).

About 2 weeks ago, I upgraded from Windows 7, I removed my "Previous Windows Installation", so my understanding is that I should now be able to upgrade to the latest version, (I should no longer have the 31 days limit).

when I do "check for update", (Update & Security), I get nothing at all. All I get is a message telling me that my system is up to date.

For fun, I downloaded the update for 1511, (KB3140768).

But if I try and install it, I get "The update is not applicable for your computer"

I could not find a standalone for build 10586, so maybe the jump to 1511 is too much?

My last update was KB3144756 and nothing since.

What could be preventing me from upgrading windows 10?

Comment: Did you use [the 64-bit version of KB3140768](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/ScopedViewInline.aspx?updateid=62cef694-cd47-4d46-be15-e0a592991d07)?

Comment: Yes, I did,I made sure I downloaded the correct one.

Comment: "About 2 weeks ago, I upgraded from Windows 7" - You are ineligible for the update, you have to wait **30 days**, before you will get it.  "I could not find a standalone for build 10586" - This is odd because every version of the .ISO that can be downloaded is this build. Build `10586` is `Version 1511`.  The best way to update your installation is to download the current .ISO, mount the .ISO, then perform the update. You can also download the `Media Creation Tool` and end up in an identical state or just way until your eligible.

Comment: [Here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench) is the current Windows 10 .ISO.  Feel free to download the Media Creation Tool if you want, when asked what you want to do, just select "Upgrade Now" if you have desire to have an installation disk.

Comment: @Ramhound, as I said in my post, I removed the "Previous Windows Installation", and that removes the 30, (or 31?) days restriction. I didn't know that ''10586'' is Version ''1511'', I cannot see any reference to that effect, finally, will using the media creation tool not overwrite everything and do a fresh install?

Comment: "will using the media creation tool not overwrite everything and do a fresh install?" - Read my comment with respect to that question.  Build [`10586`](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/10941/how-do-we-handle-windows-10-threshold-2-questions) and `Version 1511` is one in the same.  The literal build of Version 1511 is `10586.163` currently, but that is after several dozen, cumulative updates.  Its suppose to remove the 30 day restrictions but there are other eligibility conditions that must be reached.  **Far easier to just install it yourself manually, the update process, is identical**

Comment: I did read your comment, but I was under the impression that the upgrade was for versions prior to windows 10, hence the question. I did not know about ``10586`` and ``1511``, hence the question. I can see by your responses that you are annoyed with me, I must just point out that this site is to ask questions, I am sorry I do not know as much as you do and dare ask further questions. I am still curious why I am not seeing any updates as per my original post. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should try the official Microsoft tool to **perform build 10240 upgrade** :

Go to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Click on "Upgrade Now" under "The Update Assistant can help you update to the latest version of Windows 10".

Comment: This link worked for me, thanks! For posterity, this tool is called the "Windows 10 Update Assistant"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this ISO and perform the upgrade install on your PC to get 1511:

Windows 10 Tech Bench Upgrade Program
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench

How to perform upgrade install:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/wiki/insider_wintp-insider_install/how-to-perform-a-repair-upgrade-using-the-windows/35160fbe-9352-4e70-9887-f40096ec3085